# How to remove with Regex In Java

Tags: java

I have a sample data in the form of a string

```
[
  {
    "description": "Üntuk testing",
    "is_multiple_apply": true,
    "invoice": "invoice-Test",
    "fc_code": "invoice-fc-test",
    "promo_min_purchase_amount": 300,
    "promo_min_purchase_qty": 3,
    "promo_max_qty_applied": 2,
    "promo_date_end": "2020-08-15T23:59:00+0000",
    "promo_date_start": "2020-08-01T00:00:00+0000",
    "product_promo": [
      "{"plu":100,"qty":100,"discount":100,"discount_type":"AMOUNT"}"
    ]
  }
]
```

then in the **product_promo** object exactly here

> "{"plu":100,"qty":100,"discount":100,"discount_type":"AMOUNT"}"

- **there is a quote outside the curly braces** and I want to get rid of it

This is a working method for converting previous string data into available model `ProductsPromoModel`

```
public List<ProductsPromoModel> getProductsPromo() throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<ProductsPromoModel> productPromoMods = new ArrayList<>();
        
        productPromoMods = mapper.readValue(this.productsPromo.toString(), new TypeReference<List<ProductsPromoModel>>(){});
          
        return productPromoMods;
  }
```

but because there are quotes outside the curly braces. so the process occurs error

how to do it with regex?

Comment: why not simply replace `"{"`with `{"` ? (same for `}`)

Comment: The data format you have - is JSON, you need no regexp at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with regex lookaheads and lookbehinds as follows:

```
yourString.replaceAll("\"(?=\\{)|(?<=\\})\"", "");
```

Or you can do two replacements that are a little less complicated:

```
yourString.replaceAll("\"\\{", "{").replaceAll("\\}\"", "}")
```